Amazon Bedrock unable to interpret the lambda response appropriately
I am working with Bedrock to call a lambda via the action group:
Despite getting an appropriate response from Lambda, I get the below error:

The server encountered an error processing the Lambda response. Check
the Lambda response and retry the request

Lambda response:
{'messageVersion': '1.0', 'response': {'actionGroup': 'action-group-quick-start-55acd', 'function': 'connectSQL', 'functionResponse': {'responseBody': [{'total_count': 10000}]}}}

I know for a fact that certain AWS services have a restriction of 10000 results. Is it possible that your Lambda function is returning more than 10000 Items/ results throwing that error?

I found the fix. The issue was with the incorrect lambda response.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/bedrock/latest/userguide/agents-lambda.html#agents-lambda-response
Modified the lambda response to :
response_body = {
        'TEXT': {
            'body': "sample response"
        }
    }    
    function_response = {
        'actionGroup': event['actionGroup'],
        'function': event['function'],
        'functionResponse': {
            'responseBody': response_body
        }
    }    
    session_attributes = event['sessionAttributes']
    prompt_session_attributes = event['promptSessionAttributes']    
    action_response = {
        'messageVersion': '1.0', 
        'response': function_response,
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'promptSessionAttributes': prompt_session_attributes
    }

